# Como usar una variable en getElementById ( AJAX & PHP )

Tags: javascript, ajax

El código es una función en AJAX que recibe desde una página PHP 2 variables: `id` y `nombrediv`. `nombrediv` es el id del div donde quiero mostrar el resultado de la función ajax, pero no funciona.

¿Se puede hacer esto?:

```
document.getElementById(VARIABLE)
```

¿Cuál es la forma de escribirlo?

```
var editarMedidas = function(id, nombrediv) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "editar-medidas.php?id=" + id + "&nd=" + nombrediv);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if(xhr.status == 200) {
                // AQUI ES EL PROBLEMA, SE PUEDE PONER UNA VARIABLE PARA QUE BUSQUE LA DIV CON ESE NOMBRE?                  
                var caja=document.getElementById(nombrediv);     
                caja.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;     
            }        
        }                 
    }
    xhr.send(null); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar ajax para ese tipo de operaciones junto con jquery la vida te sera mucho mas fácil. En mi modesta opinión
compara:
var div = document.getElementById("div1") //Por defecto
var div = $('#div1') //usando jquery

Answer (score 0):

Si claro que es posible!, te dejo un ejemplo

```js
var aux = "contenedor";

var contenedor = document.getElementById(aux);

contenedor.innerHTML = "Estoy dentro del div" ;
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias Luciano, a ver si me podes dar una mano porque algo no me funciona...
Yo estoy enviando el nombre de la div por variable asi:
<body>
  <script src="ajax.js"></script>
  <?php
   $nombreDiv = "medidas";
  ?>
  <a href="#" onclick="traerTxt(medidas);">Ajax!</a>
  <div id="<?php echo $nombreDiv; ?>"></div>
</body>

Comment: ahi estas mostrando en el onclick el literal "medidas" dentro de los parentesis, y no el valor de $nombreDiv, que creo que es lo que comentas en tu pregunta. Lo que buscas será algo como **onclick="traerTxt('<? echo $nombreDiv;?>');">**, es decir, incrusta el valor de lo interpretado del php.

Comment: Gracias Jakala. Perdon, lo habia puesto literal para ver si funcionaba. Antes de eso tenia el codigo como lo escribiste vos. El problema es la funcion creo:
var traerTxt = function(medidas){
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
 xhr.open("GET","respuesta.txt"); 
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xhr.readyState == 4){  
   if(xhr.status == 200){ 
    var caja = document.getElementById(medidas);
    caja.innerHTML = xhr.responseText; 
   }
  }
 }
 xhr.send(null); 
}